# Postgres: Could not identify an ordering operator for type unknown

Tags: sql, postgresql, prepared-statement

I have this query with prepared statement:

```
SELECT * FROM ONLY service_services
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM fleet.service_services
WHERE deleted=false
ORDER BY $1
LIMIT $2
```

I send the value of `name ASC` to `$1` and `10` to `$2`

For some reason I am getting this error:

```
could not identify an ordering operator for type unknown
```

If I hard code the `name ASC` instead of $1, like this:

```
SELECT * FROM ONLY service_services
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM fleet.service_services
WHERE deleted=false
ORDER BY name ASC
LIMIT $1
```

It is working fine.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one column you can use `CASE WHEN` to parametrize it:

```
SELECT * FROM ONLY service_services
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM fleet.service_services
WHERE deleted=false
ORDER BY 
  CASE WHEN $1 = 'name' THEN name
       WHEN $1 = 'col_name' THEN col_name
       ELSE ...
  END
LIMIT $2;
```

or:

```
SELECT * FROM ONLY service_services
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM fleet.service_services
WHERE deleted=false
ORDER BY 
  CASE $1
       WHEN 'name' THEN name
       WHEN 'col_name' THEN col_name
       ELSE column_name -- default sorting
  END
LIMIT $2;
```

Using `CASE` you nay need to cast column to the same datatype to avoid implicit conversion errors.

**EDIT:**

```
SELECT sub.*
FROM (
    SELECT * FROM ONLY service_services
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM fleet.service_services
    WHERE deleted=false
) As sub
ORDER BY 
    CASE $1
           WHEN 'name' THEN name
           WHEN 'col_name' THEN col_name
           ELSE column_name -- default sorting
    END
LIMIT $2;
```

Comment: Thanks, but it says `invalid UNION/INTERSECT/EXCEPT ORDER BY clause` :(

Comment: @JahongirRahmonov Try for only one query without UNION

Comment: @JahongirRahmonov Try with subquery

Answer (score 1):

you can't pass column names as a variable (unless you're using dynamic query building)